# Declare struct in header file

Tags: c, struct, header-files

I want to declare a structure in a header file so I can use it in my source file. What am I doing wrong? I want to be able to access my struct from any function.

info.h

```
#ifndef INFO_H
#define INFO_H

typedef struct info
{
   int mem_size;
   int start_loc;
   int used_space;
   int free_space;
} INFO;
#endif
```

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <info.h>

#define F_first 1
#define F_last 2
#define F_data_int 3
#define F_data_char 4
#define F_data_float 5
#define F_print 6

void * f(int code);

int main() {

INFO in;
in.mem_size = 8;
f(F_last, 0,0);
return(0);
}

void * f(int code) {
printf("%d", in.mem_size);
}
```

Comment: You probably want `#include "info.h"` in your `test.c`.

Comment: gotcha. I thought "#include <info.h> was the same thing

Comment: It would help if you showed the exact compiler error message you were getting, because the 'file "info.h" not found' error would have confirmed what people are hypothesizing.

Comment: I disagree with this being too localised. It's solved a problem I was having.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace:

```
#include <info.h>
```

with,

```
#include "info.h"
```

With `<>` compiler only searches for the header file in predesignated header folder. This is used for standard library header files.
With `""` compiler first searches the header file in the local directory where your .c file is located. This is used for user defined header files.

Answer (score 1):

Yes... You must use `#include "info.h"` as opposed to `#include <info.h">` for custom based headers.  Usually they are not part of the system branch which are normally located in the `/usr/include` directory on Unix/Linux platforms.